# "Corda overlapexception in finality flow"

Tags: corda

I have been upgrade my cordapps for a new version and after this, i have reached this error: "Multiple attachments define a file at br/com/seven/contracts/cte/cteproc.class., transaction: 2AC7EF8431AAF5C91AD7C6A8E363F862E65AD821E2455164F988C93AB8B04157"]

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error when multiple jars contain that class file. Probably the old attachment with that file is still in Cordapp directory.
Make sure your file is unique across all the installed CorDapps.